# .htaccess can't redirect .pl files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Has anyone had an issue where you try and do a redirect of a .pl file and that file just shows up as forbidden?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

(http://www.oldsite.com/folder/sample.pl)
needs to redirect to...
(http://www.newsite.com/newpage/)

Here is what I have put in the .htaccess file which is located in folder on the old site (because I don't have access to the web root .htaccess file):

```
#the first line should allow the pearl file extension to execute
Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sample\.pl$ http://www\.newsite\.newpage/ [R=301,NC]
```

Though, I only get a forbidden page when I go to (http://www.newsite/folder/sample.pl).  Even without the .htaccess file in place I still get a forbidden page.  It's only .pl files that cause this forbidden page.  If I go to any of these fake pages (sample.asp, sample.jsp) they bring up the proper "Page Not Found" message.

Can anyone think of any ideas to get around this .pl extension issue?

Thank you!

Comment: It is possible that .htaccess files are only allowed in the root directory or not allowed at all.

Comment: What happens if you remove the .htaccess file? Do you also get a forbidden message, or does it show the contents of sample.pl?